# SP_Start_job fails, on local call to local execute

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I'm trying to set up a cycle to send the same report to multiple managers, with the parameters altered to suit their teams.

I've got a subscription set up which I test fired successfully, both immediately before my first attempt and after the code I've used has cycled (by setting a schedule to fire in 1 min)

However `SP_Start_job` is failing to start the job, and simply returning a 1. Every 5th run is reutrning the error:

> Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 41
>      The specified @job_id ('5274E5CB-9D5A-4998-96E4-B82017CA0588') does not exist.

```
 DECLARE @MID VARCHAR(max),
    @MEmail VARCHAR(max),
    @UpdatedSettings VARCHAR(max),
    @SubscriptionID VARCHAR(36), @passed int

--Declares a cycle getting UID for manager and their EMAIL. 
--Email will be used to update the job destination
SELECT @SubscriptionID = a.SubscriptionID
FROM ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Subscriptions] a
INNER JOIN ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Catalog] AS b ON a.[Report_OID] = b.[ItemID]
WHERE b.NAME = 'Automation OperativePerformence'  
DECLARE ManagerCursor CURSOR STATIC
FOR
(
        SELECT U.ID AS ManagerID,
            u.Email AS Email
        FROM [dbo].[Global.User] U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Global.UserRole] UR ON UR.UserId = U.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Global.Role] R ON R.ID = UR.RoleID
        WHERE R.NAME = 'ReportingAutomation'
            AND U.IsActive = 1
            AND U.Title LIKE 'Repairs Field Manager%'
        )

OPEN ManagerCursor

--UPDate cycle
FETCH NEXT
FROM managerCursor
INTO @MID,
    @MEMail

SELECT @MID,
    @MEmail

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --TEST EMAIL OVERRIDE
    SET @MEmail = 'Stephen.Wallace@email.org.uk'

UPDATE dbo.BAT_SubscriptionController
SET MID = @MID,
    MEmail = @MEmail

SELECT *
FROM BAT_SubscriptionController

    SELECT @UpdatedSettings = LEFT(Cast(a.extensionSettings AS NVARCHAR(max)), (- 1 + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', Cast(a.extensionSettings AS NVARCHAR(max))) + LEN(cast('<Name>TO</Name><Value>' AS NVARCHAR(max)))
            )) + @MEmail + RIGHT(Cast(a.extensionSettings AS NVARCHAR(max)), len(Cast(a.extensionSettings AS VARCHAR(max))) - Charindex(
            '</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>IncludeReport</Name>', Cast(a.extensionSettings AS NVARCHAR(max))) + 1)
FROM ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Subscriptions] a
INNER JOIN ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Catalog] AS b ON a.[Report_OID] = b.[ItemID]
WHERE a.SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID

SELECT @UpdatedSettings,
    LEN(@UpdatedSettings),
    @SubscriptionID

UPDATE ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Subscriptions]
SET extensionSettings = @UpdatedSettings
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID

 EXEC @passed =  msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @SubscriptionID

Select @passed

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'

FETCH NEXT
FROM managerCursor
INTO @MID,
    @MEMail
END

CLOSE ManagerCursor

DEALLOCATE ManagerCursor
```

Comment: You can try on test/dev environment to [SQL Agent](https://youtu.be/nn2FB1P_Mn8?t=15)

Comment: The 5th time you execute the code ? or the 5th iteration within the loop ?  Because you're selecting the Job_ID(SubscriptionID) outside the loop, so maybe put a trace/audit to see if some code keeps removing the job.

Comment: 5th iteration, and there's nothing shifting the job in my dev environment.

Comment: follow this link http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/11/ssrs-execute-manually-all-ssrs.html

Comment: manoj, thanks. its interesting but i can't see anything in that code that isn't placed in mine appropriatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious solution - My mistake

SP_Start_job requires The Job_Name/id , not the subscription Name ID.

Changing my Subscription ID stage to use

```
SELECT @SubscriptionID = a.SubscriptionID , @jobID= s.ScheduleID
FROM ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Subscriptions] a
INNER JOIN ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.[Catalog] AS b ON a.[Report_OID] = b.[ItemID]
    INNER JOIN ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.ReportSchedule rs
        ON rs.SubscriptionID = a.SubscriptionID
    INNER JOIN ReportServer$TOFINOREPORTING.dbo.Schedule S
        ON rs.ScheduleID = S.ScheduleID
WHERE b.NAME =
```

and the exec to 
    St_Start_job @Job_Name=@jobID

Solves the issue.

thank you @Manoj for the code. it took me multiple looks to see the obvious.